# Hyperledger Sawtooth multi-node network Error 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I have an application fully functional with a single node and a dev mode engine. I'm using docker. However, when I try to go for the multi node network with 5 containers each of validator, rest-api and poet, it gives me Error 503 service unavailable. I'm suspecting the nightly version of the images that I use to spin up the containers. Take a look at my [docker-compose](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ib_docv6bUezgR-549_ZC6qS4pu_01WDxXG0AQBKhh0/edit?usp=sharing) and [docker-compose log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L1DEFcOZ5ADndMDoXqp3AKlPszeFFliOGPDWzcJj88Q/edit?usp=sharing)

To explain what went behind, I tried to use the nightly images provided by the [sawtooth documentation](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/1.2/app_developers_guide/creating_sawtooth_network.html) which contains the links to default and POET and PBFT docker compose files. I was using the POET. The docker images used were:

```
rest-api: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly - 5 containers with this image.
validator: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly - 5 containers with this image.
settings: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:nightly - 5 containers with this image.
poet: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-engine:nightly - 5 containers with this image.
my transaction processor: cryptoport/cryptoport-python:chime - 1 container with this image.
my api:  cryptoport/cryptoport-python:chime - 1 container with this image.
```

Here is the error message:

```
cryptoport-api-default          | 172.19.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2023 08:41:32] " [35m [1mGET /get_rollups_by_coin HTTP/1.1 [0m" 500 -
cryptoport-api-default          | Traceback (most recent call last):
cryptoport-api-default          |   File "/requestops.py", line 38, in send_request
cryptoport-api-default          |     result.status_code, result.reason))
cryptoport-api-default          | exceptions.CryptoportClientException: Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Additionally, looking at the log (attached above), I could find that the transaction processor hasn't spun up either.